# How do prevent my ReactJs code to be visible on client side?

Tags: reactjs, security

Whoever accesses my react application can see all the used code in their browsers for example in 'Sources' when opening developers tools on google chrome. How can I hide it - is there any simple solution for that? Please notice that I also tried it with production build but the code is still visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to `.map` files generated in the build, They help in debugging the code in production and used to have stack trace in error loggers like `Sentry` etc

You can prevent `.map` files from being generated by setting `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` as false

you can do that by modifying the build script in `package.json` as,

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

or you can keep it in `.env` file if you have

In `.env` insert the following line

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

PS: `.env` file must me at the root of the project

Comment: I used both pieces of your advice - none of them seems to work either when running development or as production build.

Comment: @Sinny, completely delete the `build` folder before building, It works only for production

Comment: @Sinny, can you please post the contents of the build folder

Comment: don't forget the `uglifyJs`

Comment: As soon as i will have spare time I will post it ASAP

Comment: Where is the .env file typically located?

Comment: @Sinny `.env` have to be at the project root, beside `package.json`

Comment: Solution is to delete all the .map files from both css and js directories in static directory of build package

Comment: Please add that this must be at the root to your question. I accepted the answer already thanks for your afford!